# Threads killing and running problems

Tags: java, multithreading

now im working with threads, trying to learn how to code it in a right way :) And now im having problem with my code.

```
package main;
import java.util.Random;

public class Pick extends Thread
{
private Controll controll;

 public Pick(Controll controll)
{
  this.controll = controll;
}

public void run()
{

  while (true)
  {
     int itemID = generateItemID();

     try {
        controll.Pick(itemID);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    };

     System.out.println("Item: " + itemID + " picked!");
     System.out.println(controll.getFill() + " of " + controll.getPalletSize());

        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }


  }
}

public int generateItemID()
{
  Random randomGenerator = new Random();
  int itemID = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
  return itemID;
}

}
```

And other class

```
package main;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Controll
{
private ArrayList<Integer> ItemID;
private int PalletID;
private int PalletSize;
private int Fill;
private volatile boolean running = true;

 public Controll()
{
   this.ItemID = new ArrayList<>();
}

public synchronized void Pick(int itemID) throws InterruptedException

{
   while(running)
   {
     if (getPalletSize() == Fill)
     {
         terminate();
        System.out.println("Pallet is full!");
        for(int i = 0; i <ItemID.size();i++)
        {
            System.out.println(ItemID.get(i));
        }

       wait();

     }
     else
     {


  ItemID.add(itemID);
  Fill++;
  notifyAll();
     }
}
}

public synchronized int getPalletID()
{
   return PalletID;
}

public synchronized int getPalletSize()
{
    return PalletSize;
}

public synchronized void setPalletSize(int size)
{
    this.PalletSize = size;
}

public synchronized int getFill()
{
    return Fill;
}

public synchronized void setFill(int size)
{
    this.Fill = size;
}

public void terminate() {
    running = false;
}
```

}

and my test class:

```
package test;

import junit.framework.TestCase;
import main.*;

public class TestC extends TestCase {

   public void test() throws InterruptedException
   {
      Controll controll = new Controll();

      Pick pick = new Pick(controll);
      controll.setPalletSize(10);
      controll.setFill(1);


      pick.start();


      pick.join();



   }
```

}

and result what im getting is like: 
Pallet is full!
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3

im trying to make that when pallet is full it has to stop adding new items into arraylist, and it has to show every single item added into arraylist but it prints out just a arraylist what is inside, maybe someone could help me by fixing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Random correctly, you should create it once and pick how many times you need.

Change the random member into class static member. And put it under `private Controll controll;`
`private static Random RANDOM_GENERATOR = new Random();`

```
public int generateItemID()
{
  int itemID = RANDOM_GENERATOR.nextInt(100);
  return itemID;
}
```

In this scenario, we're creating random once but using it many times.
For more information read about **Pseudo Number Generator**.

Answer (score 0):

It is not showing desired behavior what u want because when u are doing `controll.Pick(itemID);` , it is calling `public synchronized void Pick(int itemID) throws InterruptedException` in Controll class. In this method, you are trying to add items to list if Pallet is not full.
So when u are executing

```
while(running)


    {
         if (getPalletSize() == getFill())
         {
             terminate();
            System.out.println("Pallet is full!");
            for(int i = 0; i <this.ItemID.size();i++)
            {
                System.out.println(this.ItemID.get(i));
            }

           wait();

         }
         else
         {


      this.ItemID.add(itemID);
      Fill++;
      notifyAll();
         }
    }
    }
```

You have already made running as true, so it will try to execute while loop until unless running gets false.In this while loop,everytime else condition will be executed until running gets false.So, it adds everytime same itemid and eventually the Pallet becomes full.That's why it is showing the output above.